# Adding in Profiles to ASP .NET MVC Project after its created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, profile

So a while back I created just a basic ASP .NET MVC Application with Visual Studio, not thinking I was going to take it too serious. Well, fast forward 3 months, and I am still looking for a job and started to code a bunch over the past 2 weeks. One of the features that I want to add are user profiles, and I know there is a an option to create the project with a 'user profile' feature built in. Unfortunately, I didn't remember to check this box, and I was wondering if there is a way to add it in after the project is already created, or would I have to build my own user system and handle the storage and security myself? Thanks for any answers or input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements to use existing template or build your own users system. To add asp.net identity to your project check this ms tutorial.

[Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for sharing the link!